# Maven can't find existing dependency in Maven Central

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a new Spring Boot 2.5.3 project and got some weird issue. I am trying to add this dependency in my pom.xml, but Maven 3.6.3 can't resolve the dependency for some reason.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

When running `mvn clean install -U` both from IDE (IntelliJ) and command prompt (bash / cmd), the printed exception is

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.myapp:api >-----------------------
[INFO] Building MyApp API 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.237 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-10T15:07:26+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project api: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myapp:api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi:jar:1.5.10 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

The dependency [exists](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/1.5.10/) in Maven Central which makes things weird.

Tried on 2 different machines with Windows and CentOS operating systems and the result is the same.

Comment: Just try `mvn package -U`...

Comment: Nothing you do on the client side will fix this.  I believe this is an issue with the pom file in Maven central.  You can downgrade to 1.3.2

Comment: @Jamven, can you share the actual error you have, which is showing up much earlier in the log? Also, `-X` flag is useful if the problem is related to the SSL connection or other such complicated cases.

Comment: @DawidPura That was the whole output, but your answer nailed to problem. Marked as solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi/1.5.10) does not have a jar type. It's POM type only.

You need to use the same dependency declaration as the Maven Central suggests:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `maven clean install`

The clean goal should recompile the project and recognize the new dependency. If that does not work, try to close down the IDE and restart it.

If the dependency is in fact in Maven central I am confident the `clean` goal will work.

Both of these options have worked for me in the past regarding dependency issues.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Modified the original post to include this info. The ```mvn clean install``` was the first thing I've tried on both machines. The IDE (IntelliJ) and the command line (bash / cmd) gives the same output as above.